Payload with Postgres: There is not enough information to infer relation
Payload version: 2.0.0 using db-postgres
With nested blocks, Postgres/Drizzle seems to be unable to create implicit tables. For example, my collection GlobalElements (elements that are the same for all pages) has a blocks field that can hold a so-called FooterBlock, which has a blocks field itself holding a FooterLinksBlock.
Have you encountered this error before? Other questions (including the one that somebody thought would answer this, but doesn't) on stackoverflow suggest this has to do with defining relations one-sided, but this is not the case here as I am working with blocks and there everything happens implicitly.
When trying to access the collection GlobalElements via the Admin Panel, an Error is thrown:
ERROR (payload): Error: There is not enough information to infer relation "global_elements._blocks_footerLinksBlock"
Even when the collection is empty, the load animation is still there.
